# How to print the objects specific member using only object name?

Tags: c++, output, operator-overloading

```
string var = "Hello";
cout << var << endl;
```

We get the result using only the object, without the help of a member variable. I want to implement a class that will work like `string`. For example:

```
class Test {
public:
    int x = 3;
};

Test var2;
cout << var2 << endl;
```

How can I get implement the class so the `cout` line prints the value of `x` without referring to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `std::string` class has operator `<<` overloaded, that's why when you write:

```
std::string text = "hello!";
std::cout << var1 << std::endl; // calling std::string's overloaded operator <<
```

Prints the text held by it simply.

Thus, you need to overload the `<<` operator for the class:

```
class Test {
    int x = 3;
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Test& t) {
        out << t.x;
        return out;
    }
}

// ...

Test var2;
std::cout << var2 << std::endl;
```